# Insertar en forma de texto valor de propiedad css en div destino

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hola necesito obtener algún medio para insertar el valor de la propiedad css "color" como texto dentro del `div#consola` para cada uno de los 3 div:

- `#position`
- `#position2`
- `#position3`

en las clases `p1color`, `p2color`, `p3color` respectivamente a medida que el valor va cambiando cuando se avanza en la barra de scroll.

```js
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ( scroll > 0 && scroll < 1000) {
  $('.position').css({
'color':'rgba(0,255,65,1.00))',
'background':'rgba(0,40,90,1.00)'
   })
  $('.position2').css({
'color':'rgba(255,248,0,1.00)',
   })
  $('.position3').css({
'color':'rgba(255,0,215,1.00)',
   })
  }
   if ( scroll > 1000 && scroll < 2000) {
  $('.position').css({
'color':'rgba(255,242,0,1.00)',
'background':'rgba(255,0,144,1.00)'
   })
  $('.position2').css({
'color':'rgba(0,100,206,1.00)',
   })
  $('.position3').css({
'color':'rgba(0,255,7,1.00)',
   })
  }
   if ( scroll > 2000 && scroll < 3000) {
  $('.position').css({
'color':'rgba(0,94,255,1.00)',
'background':'rgba(255,0,226,1.00)'
   })
  $('.position2').css({
'color':'rgba(155,0,255,1.00)',
   })
  $('.position3').css({
'color':'rgba(224,224,224,1.00)',
   })
  }
 
    if ( scroll > 3000 && scroll < 4000) {
  $('.position').css({
'color':'rgba(255,2,6,1.00)',
'background':'rgba(255,2,6,1.00)'
   })
  $('.position2').css({
'color':'rgba(69,66,179,1.00)',
   })
  $('.position3').css({
'color':'rgba(124,141,245,1.0)',
   })
  }
    if ( scroll > 4000 && scroll < 5000) {
  $('.position').css({
'color':'rgba(0,94,255,1.00)',
'background':'rgba(255,0,226,1.00)'
   })
  $('.position2').css({
'color':'rgba(224,224,224,1.00)',
   })
  $('.position3').css({
'color':'rgba(155,0,255,1.00)',
   })
  }
 if ( scroll > 5000 && scroll < 6000) {
  $('.position').css({
'color':'rgba(211,104,0,1.0)',
'background':'rgba(255,238,0,1.00)',
'text-shadow':'none'
   })
  $('.position2').css({
'color':'rgba(176,50,0,1.0)',
   })
  $('.position3').css({
'color':'rgba(100,16,5,1.00)',
   })
  }
 if ( scroll > 5000 && scroll < 6000) {
  $('.position').css({
'color':'rgba(196,173,217,1.00)',
'background':'rgba(243,255,217,1.00)',
   })
  $('.position2').css({
'color':'rgba(136,168,191,1.0)',
   })
  $('.position3').css({
'color':'rgba(68,47,168,1.0)',
   })
  }
  });
```

```css
body{text-align:center;height:10000px;}
.position{
color:blue;

 display:inline;
  margin-top:5px;
  position:fixed;
}
.position2{
color:grey;

  display:inline;
   margin-top:25px;
  position:fixed;
}
.position3{
color:green;

  display:inline;
   margin-top:45px;
  position:fixed;
}
#consola{
   background:grey;
  display:inline;
   margin-top:65px;
  position:fixed;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  margin-left:-150px;
}
.p1color{
 background:red;
}
.p2color{
 background:green;
}
.p3color{
 background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="position">
  AAAA
  </div>
<div class="position2">
  BBBBB
  </div>
<div class="position3">
  CCCC
  </div>

<div id="consola">
  <div class="p1color">
    B
    </div>
  <div class="p2color">
    C
    </div>
  <div class="p3color">
    D
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si he entendido bien la pregunta, lo que quieres es que no sólo se cambie el color del texto (cosa que ya tienes hecha), sino que también se muestre el valor del nuevo color en el div inferior (por hacer).

Si eso es lo que quieres, no tiene ningún misterio: Sólo tendrías que leer el atributo color usando el método `.css(atributo)` y asignárselo al `div` correspondiente usando `.text(valor)`. El problema de esta solución es que jQuery interpreta el valor de la propiedad y te muestra el valor equivalente (en rgb) que no es exactamente lo que tenías escrito en tu parte del código (en rgba).

Algo así:

```
$(".p1color").text($(".position").css("color"));
$(".p2color").text($(".position2").css("color"));
$(".p3color").text($(".position3").css("color"));
```

Sólo tendrías que añadir ese texto al final de tu función y ya estaría hecho:

```js
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if ( scroll > 0 && scroll < 1000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color':'rgba(0,255,65,1.00))',
      'background':'rgba(0,40,90,1.00)'
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color':'rgba(255,248,0,1.00)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color':'rgba(255,0,215,1.00)',
    })
  }
  if ( scroll > 1000 && scroll < 2000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color':'rgba(255,242,0,1.00)',
      'background':'rgba(255,0,144,1.00)'
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color':'rgba(0,100,206,1.00)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color':'rgba(0,255,7,1.00)',
    })
  }
  if ( scroll > 2000 && scroll < 3000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color':'rgba(0,94,255,1.00)',
      'background':'rgba(255,0,226,1.00)'
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color':'rgba(155,0,255,1.00)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color':'rgba(224,224,224,1.00)',
    })
  }

  if ( scroll > 3000 && scroll < 4000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color':'rgba(255,2,6,1.00)',
      'background':'rgba(255,2,6,1.00)'
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color':'rgba(69,66,179,1.00)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color':'rgba(124,141,245,1.0)',
    })
  }
  if ( scroll > 4000 && scroll < 5000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color':'rgba(0,94,255,1.00)',
      'background':'rgba(255,0,226,1.00)'
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color':'rgba(224,224,224,1.00)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color':'rgba(155,0,255,1.00)',
    })
  }
  if ( scroll > 5000 && scroll < 6000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color':'rgba(211,104,0,1.0)',
      'background':'rgba(255,238,0,1.00)',
      'text-shadow':'none'
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color':'rgba(176,50,0,1.0)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color':'rgba(100,16,5,1.00)',
    })
  }
  if ( scroll > 5000 && scroll < 6000) {
    $('.position').css({
      'color':'rgba(196,173,217,1.00)',
      'background':'rgba(243,255,217,1.00)',
    })
    $('.position2').css({
      'color':'rgba(136,168,191,1.0)',
    })
    $('.position3').css({
      'color':'rgba(68,47,168,1.0)',
    })
  }

  $(".p1color").text($(".position").css("color"));
  $(".p2color").text($(".position2").css("color"));
  $(".p3color").text($(".position3").css("color"));
});
```

```css
body{
  text-align:center;
  height:10000px;
}
.position{
  color:blue;
  display:inline;
  margin-top:5px;
  position:fixed;
}
.position2{
  color:grey;
  display:inline;
  margin-top:25px;
  position:fixed;
}
.position3{
  color:green;
  display:inline;
  margin-top:45px;
  position:fixed;
}
#consola{
  background:grey;
  display:inline;
  margin-top:65px;
  position:fixed;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  margin-left:-150px;
}
.p1color{
  background:red;
}
.p2color{
  background:green;
}
.p3color{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="position">
  AAAA
</div>
<div class="position2">
  BBBBB
</div>
<div class="position3">
  CCCC
</div>

<div id="consola">
  <div class="p1color">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="p2color">
    C
  </div>
  <div class="p3color">
    D
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias :D